# extract sub string from string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one of the following string :

```
(,QUESTION-3914~Please enter the unique identification number associated with the IRQ.|3~Greater Than|5~5,AND,QUESTION-3920~Select the contract action that applies to this IRQ.|5~Equal To|LOV1274~New Agreement,),AND,QUESTION-3921~If "New Agreement@comma@" which type of New Agreement is being requested?|5~Equal To|y~Yes,OR,NOT,(,QUESTION-3923~Will the Third Party Relationship support the implementation@comma@ pilot@comma@ launch@comma@ or operation of a New Activity (as defined in the New Activity Risk Management Policy)?|5~Equal To|y~Yes,)
```

I want required ouput for this string is like :-

```
(,QUESTION-3914|3|5,AND,QUESTION-3920|5|LOV1274,),AND,QUESTION-3921|5|y,OR,NOT,(,QUESTION-3923)|5|y,)
```

What should i do for this ?

Comment: What are the rules that lead from A to B?

Comment: You should filter the string so it doesn't contain the parts you don't.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev : I dont get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression to replace everything from each `~` tilde character until the next comma `,` or pipe `|` character (exclusive of that final character):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_data ( input_string ) AS
SELECT '(,QUESTION-3914~Please enter the unique identification number associated with the IRQ.|3~Greater Than|5~5,AND,QUESTION-3920~Select the contract action that applies to this IRQ.|5~Equal To|LOV1274~New Agreement,),AND,QUESTION-3921~If "New Agreement@comma@" which type of New Agreement is being requested?|5~Equal To|y~Yes,OR,NOT,(,QUESTION-3923~Will the Third Party Relationship support the implementation@comma@ pilot@comma@ launch@comma@ or operation of a New Activity (as defined in the New Activity Risk Management Policy)?|5~Equal To|y~Yes,)' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( input_string, '~.*?([|,])', '\1' ) AS output
FROM   your_data d
```

**Output**:

```
| OUTPUT                                                                                               |
| :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| (,QUESTION-3914|3|5,AND,QUESTION-3920|5|LOV1274,),AND,QUESTION-3921|5|y,OR,NOT,(,QUESTION-3923|5|y,) |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d6bcc2eeacd9036c39c4ece88e803846)*